# Copy rows from several Excel books into a new Excel book

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to copy rows from several books in to a new book. I'm going to try explain.
I have book1, book2 and book3, and I would like to copy rows that have a specific word in the column D from those to book4.
Is there any way to do that?

Comment: don't put a signature in the question. please fill out your profile.

Comment: Since you tagged it as excel-vba, I am going to awesome you want an automated solution. Please ask yourself if you really need one? If the answer is yes, then to answer your question `Is there any way to do that?`, Yes, there is! I'll go even a step further and tell you to do it manually with one example while the macro recorder is on to begin to  learn how to do it. I'll also refer you to the [FAQ]:www.stackoverflow.com/faq so you can learn how to get more meaningful answers out of the site. In short, if you give some example of what you are trying that is failing, we can help much easier:)

Comment: did you get the answer that you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Sort by 'column D' and then all the data that you want to grab will be grouped together, select it all and copy.

**Edit**

Select all the Data, then go to the `Data` Tab at the top and click on sort.